# What does the namespace std add? (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I am currently working in c++, I want to know everything that using namespace std adds. I already know the basic ones, like cout and cin. However when I run my program without using namespace std, It doesn't work (I do add std:: before the cout command). But I am wondering what else I need to add std:: before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyClass{
public:
    void setName(string x){
        name = x;
    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
private:
    string name;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass mc;
    mc.setName("WASSSSSUUUPP!!! \n");
    std::cout << mc.getName();
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp

Comment: Also If anyone has a link to a page about the namespace std that would be awesome!

Comment: @killarviper chris just did that, here's all the header files listed on that page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header I'm sure you can find <string> and <iostream> there

Comment: If it seems a bit overwhelming, that's precisely why this is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - All the entities (variables, types, constants, and functions) of the standard C++ library are declared within the `std` namespace. `using namespace std;` introduces direct visibility of all the names of the std namespace into the code.

ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

2 - Namespaces in C++ are most often used to avoid naming collisions. Although namespaces are used extensively in recent C++ code, most older code does not use this facility. For example, the entire C++ standard library is defined within `namespace std`, but before standardization many components were originally in the global namespace.

ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace#Use_in_common_languages

Comment: Dr. Stroustrup recommends avoiding namespace usage in header files.

Comment: @Vector, I agree, [that is considered bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).